# how do I delete search history on Firefox on an Android phone

Tags: stock-android, firefox-for-android

I've been reading countless articles about deleting the search engine history on Firefox on my Android phone.

Let me be clear: I'm not talking about clearing my browser history, rather clearing the search history, which still remains after I've cleared my browsing history.

None of the said articles helped.

Attached is a picture of problem.

I'm running Firefox 57.0.4

[image: img1]

Answer (score 3):

Firefox settings → Clear Private data → clear search history

[image]