# Firefox Android Clearing download history without deleting the file

Tags: firefox-for-android

On the desktop version of Firefox, when I open "Show All Downloads" and there "Clear Downloads", the history of downloads is cleared, but the downloaded files are present in the folder still. This is the desired behavior.

However, on Android Firefox, if I open Tools->Downloads, I only get the option "Delete All Downloads" and when I press it, the list gets cleared, along with the files from the folder. How do I avoid this and get the behavior similar to that in the desktop? Basically, I wish to clear Firefox download history in Android without deleting/renaming the downloaded files.

Comment: [Doesn't clear search & browser history not clear?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/189917/131553)

Comment: @beeshyams It does clear the download history, but it also deletes all the files in the list from the folder.

Comment: In Menu->Tools->Downloads

Comment: Maybe you can use an app like [folder sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) to sync your downloads on schedule /demand, if you don't get Firefox based solution

Comment: I would prefer a solution within Firefox. Or that the developers fix this. However, until then, I might have to fall back to FolderSync.